# Why does $\frac{49}{64}\cos^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta$ equal $\frac{113}{64}\cos^2 \theta $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, arithmetic, fractions

I have an example:

$$ \frac{49}{64}\cos^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1 $$

Then what happens next:

$$ \frac{113}{64}\cos^2 \theta = 1 $$

Where has the other cosine disappeared to? What operation happened here? Any hints please.

Comment: $\frac{49}{64}\cos^2(\theta) + \frac{64}{64}\cos^2(\theta) = 1$. So adding those two fractions gives you the coefficient $\frac{113}{64}$.

Comment: Here's a hint:  look at $1 + (49/64)$.  Cheers!

Comment: If you have $\frac{49}{64}$ of a potato, and add a whole potato to that, you have, in total, $1\frac{49}{64}$ of a potato as a mixed number. Converting that mixed number to an improper fraction, you have $\frac{113}{64}$ of a potato.

Comment: I would just like to add a comment here that I appreciate that the answers and comments here were not condescending in the slightest. You can't expect that from other sites on this network, especially stackoverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a simple use of the distributive law ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)):
$$ac+bc=(a+b)c$$
In this situation,
$$\left(\frac{49}{64}\right)\cos^2(\theta)+\left(1\right)\cos^2(\theta)=\left(\frac{49}{64}+1\right)\cos^2(\theta)=\left(\frac{113}{64}\right)\cos^2(\theta)$$

Answer (score 6):

By distributive law, $$\frac{49}{64}\cos^2 \theta+\cos^2 \theta=\left(\frac{49}{64}+1\right)\cos^2 \theta=\left(\frac{49}{64}+\frac{64}{64}\right)\cos^2 \theta=\left(\frac{49+64}{64}\right)\cos^2 \theta.$$ and the numerator $$49+64=113.$$

Answer (score 4):

$\dfrac{49}{64}\cos^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = \left(\dfrac{49}{64} +1\right) \cos^2 \theta =  \dfrac{113}{64}\cos^2 \theta$